# Proof - expectation of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, expectation

A discrete random variable $X >0$

Can you prove : $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{x>0} \mathbb{P}[ X >= x ]$$

I don't get the question - is it asking for a generic proof or to find an $x$ which satisfies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The right statement should be $EX=\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X\geq x)$, the index $x$ must belong to $\mathbb N$, not $\mathbb R_+$.

We have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X\geq x) &=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{n=x}^\infty P(X=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{x=1}^n P(X=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(X=n)=EX.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you clarify in the last step why  sum of 1 to n = n? Apolgies if it is an obvious question.

Comment: Because $\sum_{x=1}^n 1=n$.

Comment: is the same approached applied in the continuous case?

Comment: In general, if $X\geq 0$ then $EX=\int_0^\infty P(X\geq x)dx$ and the method to prove is similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for a generic proof.

Hint: Start with the definition of expectation and assume $X\in \Bbb N^+$. $$\mathsf E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x~\mathsf P(X=x)$$

> $x=\sum_{y=1}^x y

Then show the conclusion also holds for non-integer support intervals.